# Use of interface with no methods

Tags: oop, marker-interfaces

I've simplified down the real code into the smallest example that illustrated the point.  Excuse the lack of setters/getters, etc.

Imagine we have a couple of web pages that a customer goes through in sequence.  The use case here is:-

- User selects which book they want
- User selects if they want it sent via post or email and associated details
- System fulfils the order

This quesiton is focused on the two ways of delivering.  This is modelled as follows:

```
interface DeliveryDetails
{
    // Implementations of this have nothing in common other than that they
    // fulfil the same logical role.
}

class EmailDeliveryDetails implements DeliveryDetails
{
    String emailAddress;  // It really has a constructor and getter, I promise.
}

class PostalDeliveryDetails implements DeliveryDetails
{
    String streetAddress;
    String Country;
}
```

Now, to represent the information entered by the user when going through the pages, we have this class:

```
class PurchaseData
{
    String title;
    DeliveryDetails deliveryDetails;
}
```

As the user steps through the web pages, information is stored in an instance of `PurchaseData`.  If the user goes back a page, we can show them what they previously entered.  After the user has confirmed and it is time to deliver the book, `deliveryDetails` references an instance of `PostalDeliveryDetails` or `EmailDeliveryDetails`.

On conclusion, when the user confirms their information:

```
    // Some code in a factory
    if ( purchaseData.deliveryDetails instanceof EmailDelivery )
    {
        // construct a EmailDeliveryService( purchaseData, SMTP details, etc ... )
    }
    if ( purchaseData.deliveryDetails instanceof PostalDelivery )
    {
        // construct a PostalDeliveryService( purchaseData, etc ... )
    }
}
```

It troubles me that `Delivery` interface has no methods.

This is forced by the differences between email and postal delivery.

I do not think that `DeliveryDetails.deliver()` is a good method as this would force implementations to get things like the SMTP server address statically.  This confuses concerns (plumbing vs. information entered by a user).

If you have to store something of arbitary type, generics can be useful.  It is not possible to use generics (`PurchaseData<T extends Delivery>`) because the delivery type is not known when the PurchaseData instance is created.  Anyway, this would not help in the factory.

Is this empty interface ok?  Is there a better way to design this code?

Comment: I don't see any problems with empty interfaces. I have seen such interfaces many a times, and with your approach it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the (data) differences between `EmailDeliveryDetails` and `PostalDeliveryDetails` boil down to addresses. So my first instinct would be to extract that data into a separate Address class. Then you may decide to have a single Address with optional fields for emailAddress and streetAddress, or a class hierarchy with distinct subclasses for email and postal addresses.

I would prefer the single class with optional fields, as it is cleaner to use, and to me practicality trumps conceptual "purity".

#### Update

Based on the comment chain below:

When there is no overlap between the properties (thus the possible states) of specific classes, it is very awkward to try to handle them polymorphically. And if one doesn't intend to put much functionality into them either, it is even more difficult to handle them in distinct classes inheriting some common interface (as you too noted). OTOH conceptually all of this is some sort of address data, so it can be handled in one class.

Note that most of this is speculation though - it is difficult to reason about your design without more detailed information.

> You are right in that I don't intend to put much behaviour in `EmailDeliveryDetails` and `PostalDeliveryDetails`. In the real application, these details would be persisted in the database and details sent through to outside systems.

Ah OK, so you aren't actually going to treat them polymorphically. You only need a common "handle" to access different bits of data to be persisted. And persistence typically doesn't care about polymorphism and interfaces anyway. In this case having your classes inherit from an empty interface is fine.

Comment: There's no overlap in private members between EmailDeliveryDetails and PostalDeliveryDetails it seem troubling to put them in the same class.  This gets worse as more options are added.

Comment: @WW. exactly because there is no overlap (and if I understand you correctly, you don't intend to put much functionality into them either), it is difficult to handle them in distinct classes inheriting some common interface (as you too noted). OTOH conceptually all of this is some sort of address data, so it can be handled in one class.

Comment: @WW. you don't show us how are you using DeliveryDetails in your app - what logic or methods do the concreet subclasses contain? Who is using these? It is difficult to reason about your design with so little information.

Comment: You are right in that I don't intend to put much behaviour in EmailDeliveryDetails and PostalDeliveryDetails.  In the real application, these details would be persisted in the database and details sent through to outside systems.

Comment: @WW., ok, in this case having them inherit from an empty interface is fine.

Comment: I would like to choose this as the answer, but more for the comments than the answer.  Care you edit your answer?

Comment: @WW. I edited my answer to incorporate the comments, hope this makes it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your implementation classes are some sort of descriptors and they don't actually do anything. To me it feels cleaner to use a class hierarcy in this situation (abstract base class with two subclasses: EmailDeliveryDetails and PostalDeliveryDetails) even if the base class is empty.
EmailDeliveryDetails **is a** DeliveryDetail and not a Delivery implementation unless it implements a deliver method.

Comment: Interesting: I have not given much throught to Abstract Class vs. Interface.  For brevity I omitted that those classes actually extend `ReflectionToString` to pickup some behaviour and can not multiple inherit in java.  (Usually I prefer composition but in that case got a bit lazy I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

A double dispatch approach like the one outlined below could work, but might be overkill in this scenario. I'll mention it just to give you some options...

```
class DeliveryService {
    // base class doesn't handle anything
    process(EmailDelivery details) {}
    process(PostalDelivery details) {}    
}

class EmailDeliveryService extends DeliveryService {
    process(EmailDelivery details) { /* handle */ }
}

class PostalDeliveryService extends DeliveryService {
    process(PostalDelivery details) { /* handle */ }
}

interface DeliveryDetails {
    processWith(DeliveryService service);
}

class EmailDeliveryDetails implements DeliveryDetails {
    processWith(DeliveryService service) { service.process(this); }
}

// try all services (of unknown type) on the given details (also of unknown type)
List<DeliveryService> services = configureServices();
DeliveryDetails details = getDetails();
for (DeliverySerivce service : services) details.processWith(service);
```

If new types of DeliveryDetails (perhaps unlikely...) are added you have to update DeliveryService (adding an empty process method) and add a new type of DeliveryService that actually does something with the new type of DeliveryDetails.

Optionally, the process and processWith methods could return booleans to indicate whether or not the details are processed.

Again, this approach is probably unnecessarily complex in this case, but it addresses the issue of handling unknown delivery types you raise at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but I don't think I'd go with this option.  Also, how would you imagine the configuration (SMTP address, etc) would reach the EmailDeliveryService?

Comment: For sake of brevity I left out the configureServices() method, but It would of course do something like services.add(new EmailDeliveryService(options)); Or really, the delivery services would be set up once, in some other part of the system, and then made accessible where needed.

Comment: Thanks - I understand.  I think it's conceptually better to pass the DeliveryDetails to the service and not the other way around.  This leaves me with the empty interface, but maybe that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

`EmailDeliveryDetails` and `PostalDeliveryDetails` have in common only the concept of "delivery", but neither their behaviour, nor their knowledge is the same. The common ancestor `DeliveryDetails` is not suitable in this case.

Personally, I would create an inheritance tree from `PurchaseData`.

Comment: So, EmailPurchaseData and PostalPurchaseData?  I would not know which one to create initially, so that would mean recreating an object later in the flow through the wizard.  In the real system, this happens on a couple of different things so I would end up with lots of combinations.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this problem, I don't think you even need two classes. In any case, you'll capture the email address and optionally the postal address if the user wants it delivered that way. Polymorphism is an overkill; just use a simple condition to determine the delivery method.